# Any way to use decimal font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

Is there any way to use decimal font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?
By default it shows error 'Size must be a number'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Don't even try.

While it's possible to edit the preferences file on disk or export it, change the font size and import it again, the internal field type is `int` in all important places (like the text editor when it calculates the line height). So even if you could smuggle in a decimal value, that would just cause tons of problems in many places.